# How to resolve MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/plain exception?

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I am facing `MessageBodyReader Not Found Exception` while reading the entity back. I am sending the entity as byte stream. In my service I am having application/xml as the media type but on the trace it says for text/plain.

stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/plain;charset=utf-8, type=class com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.provider.docusign.rest.model.response.SendDocumentsResponse, genericType=class com.mercuryinsurance.esignature.integration.provider.docusign.rest.model.response.SendDocumentsResponse.
```

Comment: Can you post the code? on both ends.

Comment: Add this at your client side  builder.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);